# After dropping a user in SSMS, what should I check?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I did something stupid, I think I fixed it, and I would like to know if there is anything obvious I missed or should check. I'm a first-time DBA who has formal training for only some operations within SSMS 2008 R2. I have a moderate to good understanding of SQL and that knowledge is growing fairly rapidly. I'm still making some mistakes.

Today I created a user and, on autopilot, accidentally hit Enter after giving her a password. I had meant to uncheck Enforce Password Expiration and User must change password at next login. The user was mapped to three databases.

The stupid thing I did was in deciding to delete the login in the server, delete the login from each of the three databases, and recreate the login. Obviously this should not have been my solution. Obviously again, attempting to recreate the login returned an error: "The server principal FOO already exists..." This was error 15025.

So I found that sure enough, there was a row in sys.server_principles for FOO row. I used Drop User to get rid of it, then checked again and it was gone. Great, recreate the login. New error: "User, group, or role already exists in the current database..." Error number 15023. This also added a new row for FOO back into sys.server_principal, which I dropped again.

So then I recreated the login without any mapping, which worked. Then I tried adding the mapping but got the same error 15023, which didn't surprise me. I used Alter User FOO with login = FOO. Ran successfully. Tried adding the mapping again, same error. I tried adding each mapping one at a time and found that two of the three databases I could map just fine, but the third one was a problem.

Finally, I closed SSMS and reopened it, and for some reason I was now able to map the third database. It is probable that closing and reopening SSMS did nothing, I don't see why it would, but I don't know what caused the mapping to fail previously and work that last time.

I have tested the login and it works for all of the databases. I'm wondering if there is any cleanup I should perform or look into, or any concern I should have. I do have daily full and hourly transaction backups, but as the databases are in use right now I obviously hope not to have to use them.

So obviously I messed up and I won't be doing that again. Any places to check, concerns, or assurances would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any issue in this case. For yours reference, if we want to remove the user, 1) we need to remove the user from each database that user have association 2) remove the user from logins of server. Keep learning you become a master ....

Comment: Thanks for your comment, especially the encouragement at the end!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that the mapping is correct with the following query:

```
select name, suser_sname(sid) as [login]
from sys.database_principals
where name = 'foobar'
```

The `suser_sname(sid)` function will take a security identifier (sid) and map it back to the server-level login. Run that in each database you're concerned about and ensure that the login is indeed what you expect it to be. If it's not, you already know how to fix it (the `alter user … with login = …) is the right move there).

As an aside, part of your story doesn't quite match up for me. You said that you were checking sys.database_principals to see whether the login existed or not. The thing is that logins are in sys.server_principals (whereas users for each individual database are in sys.database_principals). This may account for the trouble you had.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just checked and the results are as expected/desired, so all is indeed well. I am grate for you taking time time to help me confirm that this is resolved.